# How to persist java.util.Set through JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, set

I have a field `aliases` of type `java.util.Set` in one `Entity`. This `Set` doesn't denote any relationship to an Entity.

1. How can I store this `aliases` field through JPA?
2. How this field get stored in database? I think that for the database, this field is a multi-valued attribute.

Comment: @Bozho Yes, `aliases` is `String`. My persistence-provider is toplink-essentials

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I store this aliases field through JPA?

JPA 1.0 doesn't support collections of basic types so you'll have to either:

1. Introduce an entity and map it as a `@OneToMany` ~or~
2. Get your `Set` stored in a BLOB (as a `Serializable`) ~or~
3. Mark it `@Transient` and use another getter/setter to store it using a custom string representation (using a seperator) ~or~
4. Use an extension of your JPA provider supporting collection of basic types (e.g. Hibernate has the [`@CollectionOfElements`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionOfElements.html) annotation).

Solution  #1 would be the cleanest portable solution. Solution #2 can lead to some troubles on upgrades. Solution #3 is a ugly workaround for #2. Solution #4 is clean but non portable.

In JPA 2.0, there is the [`@ElementCollection`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) annotation for this use case (this is of course the ideal solution).

> How this field get stored in database

Depending on the chosen implementation, it may be in a BLOB, in a VARCHAR, in another table.